# basic jquery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this main page

index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load('page.html');

    $("#menu").click(function () {
       alert('Hello');
    });
});
<script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

and in page.html

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the .load is working ..
but the alert function is not working

must i but the function in page.html???
or there is another way ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your code to bind to `#menu` runs before the sub-page is loaded.  You need to either use `on` or do the bind inside the call back which runs once the load completes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load('page.html', function() {
      $("#menu").click(function () {
         alert('Hello');
      });
    });
});
```

Version with `on`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').load('page.html');

    $('#content').on('click', '#menu', function() {
       alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the content is dynamically loaded, you need to use `live()` (for jQuery <1.7) or `on()` (1.7+).

These functions delegate events to dynamic elements along with ones that existed on page load.

Here's how it would look with `on()`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu", function(){
    alert("Menu clicked.")
});
```

Comment: That actually won't work - `#menu` would need to be present at the time that code runs, which it's not.  You've got the same problem as OP in his original code.  You can either bind the event in the load callback, or do `$(document).on("click", "#menu", function()`  (and I didn't downvote, in case someone comes along after me and does)

Answer (score 0):

Since the element with the id of menu is being loaded you need to use `on`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load('page.html');

    $(document).on('click', '#menu', function () {
       alert('Hello');
    });
});
<script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: The quotes around `document` need to be removed since it isn't a selector but an object.